# want to count documents in Couchdb

Tags: erlang, couchdb

https://github.com/benoitc/couchbeam/blob/master/doc/couchbeam_view.md#count1

couchbeam_view:count()/1, count/2, count/3 with all_docs returns count including design document if exist, how do I get count of docs excluding design document.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with couchbeam, but in couchdb itself all_docs uses the doc `_id` for a key for normal docs or `_design/design_name` for design docs.

So if you use the `count/3` format with an option of `endkey="_"` or (`{"endkey":"_"}`) then it should only count the non-design docs.